# Why the pins of a port in some microcontrollers are not in order?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, microprocessor, circuit-design, vlsi

In some ICs the pin numbers are not in proper order. For example, in msp430x12x2 series (following pic).
[image]

In the pic, why don't P2.0 be available at pin 20 (or adjacent to P1.0 ??)

Why is that few pins of both ports P2 and P3 are on either sides of the IC?

Comment: Note here that Port 3 is on the 8 extra pins that wouldn't be there on a 20-pin package, splitting Port 2... I'm sure there's a reason for that... I'm guessing there are also similar MCUs (probably older) where P2.5 is something else altogether and they only have P2.0 to P2.4...

Answer (score 2):

They **are** pretty much in order- counterclockwise increasing by bit number and separated by port number.

They are organized by port (internally the data bus will be so organized, and the way you access the bits is similar) so you would not expect to find the LSB of one port next to the LSB of another.

That said, there are various reasons why some microcontrollers might actually appear to have 'out of order' pins. One chip I am using right now has pins in bit order C5/C4/C3/C6/C7. It may be for backward compatibility or some other reason- the important thing is to pay attention to the datasheet.